# How to access MessageHeaders in Kafka batch listener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have the below Autoconfiguration class for Kafka:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@ConditionalOnClass(KafkaReceiver.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty({"spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers"})
public class KafkaAutoConfiguration<T> { @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")

    private String bootstrapServers;

    private KafkaProperties kafkaConfig;
    private String groupId;

    @Autowired
    public void setKafkaProperties(KafkaProperties properties) {
        this.kafkaConfig = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getGroupId());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper headerMapper(){
        return new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
    }

    @Bean("simpleReceiver")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "simpleReceiver")
    @ConditionalOnProperty({"service.kafka.consumer.topics"})
    public KafkaReceiver simpleReceiver() {
        return new KafkaSimpleReceiver();
    }

    @Bean("batchReceiver")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "batchReceiver")
    @ConditionalOnProperty({"service.kafka.consumer.batch-topics"})
    public KafkaReceiver batchReceiver() {
        return new KafkaBatchReceiver();
    }
}
```

Simple listener bean:

```
public class KafkaSimpleReceiver implements KafkaReceiver {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${service.kafka.consumer.topics}'.split(',')}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord record, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws KafkaException {
    }
}
```

Batch listener bean:

```
public class KafkaBatchReceiver implements KafkaReceiver {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${service.kafka.consumer.batch-topics}'.split(',')}", containerFactory = "kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(List<ConsumerRecord> records, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws KafkaException {

    }
}
```

Simple listener is working fine, but I am getting the following error for batch listener. How can we access MessageHeaders in this case?

```
A parameter of type 'List<ConsumerRecord>' must be the only parameter (except for an optional 'Acknowledgment' and/or 'Consumer')
```

**EDIT**

This is what I did to convert `ConsumerRecord` to `MessageHeaders`

```
public void receive(List<ConsumerRecord> records) { 
    for(ConsumerRecord record : records) { 
        Map<String, Object> headersList = new HashMap<>(); 
        for(final Header h : record.headers()) { 
            headersList.put(h.key(), new String(h.value())); 
        } 
    MessageHeaders headers = new MessageHeaders(headersList); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is an example for spring 1.5 not sure if it fits your case https://codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-batch-listener-example.html are you using reactor kafka?

Comment: It's using the signature `receive(List<String> data, @Header...)` whereas I need `ConsumerRecord`

Comment: If you need the complete `ConsumerRecord` then why do you need separate headers? The `ConsumerRecord` contains the headers. But see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of `Message<?>`.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "so54086076", id = "so54086076")
public void listen(List<Message<?>> records) {
    System.out.println(records.size() + ":" + records);
}
```

The message payloads will be the `ConsumerRecord.value()`; the other `ConsumerRecord` properties will be in the headers.

Comment: what is the difference between using `public void receive(List<ConsumerRecord> records)` and `public void listen(List<Message<?>> records)`

Comment: The framework maps each `ConsumerRecord` to a `spring,messaging` `Message<?>` where the payload is the `value()` and headers contain other properties (topic. partition, offset, etc), as well as any user-defined headers.

Comment: Is this approach fine to convert ConsumerRecord to MessageHeaders?
`public void receive(List<ConsumerRecord> records) {
  for(ConsumerRecord record : records) {
   Map<String, Object> headersList = new HashMap<>();
   for(final Header h : record.headers()) {
    headersList.put(h.key(), new String(h.value()));
   }
   MessageHeaders headers = new MessageHeaders(headersList);
             }
     }`

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's too hard to read; edit the question instead. You can also use a `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` (`toHeaders()`) to populate the map - it will do any JSON decoding (e.g. if the headers were created by a header mapper on the sending side - for example by a Spring Integration application).